# How to make navigation bar clear?

Tags: usability, navigation, menu

I have a website titled 'Ibiza Party People'. I've made 3 buttons like:

Ibiza(About us page)-Party(Photography page)-People (Blog page).

This is a screenshot of how the menu looks like: 
[image]

I have the impression that something is wrong in terms of user experience because this may be confusing for a user to notice that this is a menu.
What do you think about this ? It's a good approach or is something totally wrong?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to why you think it could be confusing?

Comment: Because of the menu buttons, they are like the name of the domain, so I think people may think that that is somehow a tagline or a slogan...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty much wrapping up the navigation and the site name/logo in the same package. While this might seem slick and cool, it breaks with the convention of "don't make me think" for the visitor because only after wondering, then trial and error, is the visitor able to note what each link does - IF they ever even discover each word is a link. If you'd still like to keep your words as links though, I'd probably suggest placing a small, flat icon under each word (such as a camera under "party") and add a padded, light border around the word and icon. This way you have 3 distinct elements that tell you they're likely click-able and a hint as to what you might expect from it. The idea is to not have the user ever wonder about what how your page works, but to make it as easy for them to get what you're offering. Leave the hidden meaning, clever stuff for marketing ads. ;P

Answer (score 4):

> Ibiza(About us page)-Party(Photography page)-People (Blog page).

The problem is the terms don't match the content. Your menu should be:

```
about | photos | blog
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a problem to begin with - we'd need to see the site itself and see whether it looks like a navigation menu in the bigger picture. But in any case, if that's what worries you, just add separators and you'll be fine.
[image]